# More precise command prompt default size

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Is there a way to set the default command prompt size more precisely ?
When I right click on the cmd window and adjust its height, I can't get it to fit perfectly the way I want.
Ideally, I would like to put it in the bottom left corner, but I can't get it exactly right.

Comment: Try something like `mode con: cols=160 lines=78` and then press `ENTER`. Adjust the 160 and 78 numbers to get something you like, and then just plan to use that when you open command prompt each time.

Comment: I don't get the right result, it might depend on the zoom level (mine is 125%) and the resolution (1920*1080). I will try to play around with it.

Comment: It sure might, just play with the numbes until you get something close to what you're looking for as a quick way to set it manually.  Otherwise, you can click on the properties of the CMD title bar and look over the settings from those tabs.

Comment: It is what I originally did, but I can't get the perfect result.

Comment: See here too: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491037.aspx. What's "right" to you is your opinion and not a fact in this context.  Here's another article as well with some ideas.  It may or may not be possible to get your personal "perfect" solution in this case but these are some quick ideas with some quick searches on the web or what I know about otherwise.  Perhaps someone can answer this perfectly for you otherwise for the perfect answer you're looking for--but there are some things to look over in the meantime. Best of luck Max version 37!!

Comment: Forgot the other link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945527/modify-cmd-exe-properties-using-the-command-prompt

Comment: Right click on the top frame of the cmd window and go to Properties. There you can make the settings.

Comment: By "perfectly right", I meant by making it take exactly the bottom left quarter of the screen (sorry if I wasn't clear), and the different means you quoted are not allowing me to place it exactly in this position because the height parameter indicates the number of lines and not the height in pixels. What I'm searching for is a way to set the height in pixels.

Comment: You can't set the height in pixels. In addition the height (in pixels) will change depending on what font you are using ...